# Section references in RevTex 4.1

Tags: cross-referencing, revtex

How does one reference sections in RevTex4.1? I've tried

- `\section{\label{sec:Coupling}Coupling Efficiency}`
- `\section{Coupling Efficiency\label{sec:Coupling}}`
- `\section{Coupling Efficiency}\label{sec:Coupling}`

But, in all cases `\ref{sec:Coupling}` has no error but simply prints a white space.

Here is a small doc that demonstrates the probelm (for one permutation):

```
\documentclass[12pt,preprint,longbibliography,aps,prl]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\title{stuffing}
\author{John doe}

\begin{abstract}
stuff stuff stuff
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
stuff stuff reference~\ref{sec:Coupling}

\section{\label{sec:Coupling}Coupling Efficiency}
stuff

\end{document}
```

Comment: all of those should work, please make a complete (small) document that shows the problem.

Comment: The third option is the best, by the way.

Comment: If you `\label{sec:Coupling}` but `\ref{sec:Expectation}` you should get an error about undefined references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the `prl` option of REVTeX section numbering is omitted, hence no reference is typeset, because plain `\ref` retrives only the section number. If you cancel this option you will have working references again.

[image: output]

Comment: Oy, this was a pain to track down.  If the 'prl' option is removing section numbers, it really should throw a warning whenever you try to label a section with `\label`.